# How to Insert money datatype value in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hi I am new to postgres,
while inserting the data into a money type field I am getting the error as.. 
Here my sample table is as

```
CREATE TABLE x_table
(
  t_name character varying(40) NOT NULL,
  currency money
)

INSERT INTO x_table(t_name, currency)
VALUES ('TEST', 1000);
```

and getting the error message as
`ERROR: column "currency" is of type money but expression is of type integer
SQL state: 42804`.

So can any one say how to resolve this..
Thanks in advance

Comment: As always: your version of Postgres? In modern versions, this just works.

Comment: Store currency in cents using big integer. Not an answer but may work equally well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In modern versions (tested with 9.1 and 9.3) the above code example works *as is*.

In older versions there was no implicit cast defined from `integer` to `money`.
[Quoting the the release notes for Postgres 9.1:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/release-9-1.html)

> Add support for casting from `int4` and `int8` to `money` (Joey Adams)

Also, be sure to consider alternatives to store currency information:
[PostgreSQL: Which Datatype should be used for Currency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15726535/postgresql-which-datatype-should-be-used-for-currency/15729573)

Comment: Thanks Erwin,Worked with 9.1 and may I know to use that money to int casting while inserting from the command prompt... if we are using in the older versions