# What's the best data type to store data of a bank?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I was wondering what's the best data type for transaction amounts (in euro) of a bank ?
Example : 
The person "A" sends 120.59 euros to "B"

What's the best data type to store this data (120.59) in a database ?
the transaction amount is positive, 2 digits after the decimal, and it will be used in calculations after (sum of amounts, averages, variance and standard-deviations...etc).
Is it okey to use REAL ? DECIMAL is ok ?

Comment: Presumably, https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-money.html

Comment: @Blorgbeard: [do **not** use the money type](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_money)

Comment: No, I'm wrong: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15726535/postgresql-which-datatype-should-be-used-for-currency

Comment: Oops, forgot I have a sql hammer. @a_horse is the dupe appropriate?

Comment: @Blorgbeard: I think so, yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not want to store monetary amounts using floating point numbers.

You want to store them using fixed point -- that is `numeric`/`decimal`.  For your example, it would be something like `numeric(10, 2)`.  However, you might want fractions of a cent for some reason, so larger precision and scale such as `numeric(20, 4)` is a good idea.