# How to insert salary "NULL" in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

How do I implement a sql command which outputs NULL for salary if it is a voluntary worker?
Here are the tables I created first:

```
create Table worker (
pid integer references Person,
salary float);

create Table person(
pid integer primary key,
name varchar(30),
adress varchar(30));
```

Since I'm not sure how to distinguish a normal worker from a voluntary one, I decided to make another table. Unfortunately, I don't know how to insert NULL values for salary for all voluntary workers. That is what I tried out:

```
create table voluntaryworker(
pid integer references Person,
salary = null);

insert into Person (pid, name, adress) values (1345, anna, 'festreet');
insert into voluntaryworker (pid, salary) values (1345, null);
```

pid = person ID

Comment: I'd consider salary 0 instead, since the salary is known to be 0.

Comment: Why bother having a `salary` column in that table at all, if it is always `0` or `NULL`?  Also, you should tag with the database you are using.

Comment: Re the relational algebra post you just deleted: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For RA give what you can. Which is a lot--you are using a system executing RA. Isolate the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what & why (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like others commented, you certainly don't need another table to implement this. All you need is some way to remember whether a worker is voluntary.

To make sure `salary` sticks to your rule, you can add a [`CHECK` constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-CHECK-CONSTRAINTS):

```
CREATE TABLE worker (
  pid       integer PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES person
, voluntary boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false
, salary    numeric
, CONSTRAINT voluntary_has_no_salary CHECK (NOT voluntary OR salary IS NULL)
);
```

Meaning: voluntary workers cannot have a nonnull salary.

Alternatively, you might drop the table `worker`, too, and just add the columns `worker_salary` and `worker_voluntary` to table person. (You may need an additional flag `worker`, or integrate this information in the other two columns ...)

If you are still interested in [generated columns](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html) (not needed here), see this example with correct syntax and instructions:

- [Computed / calculated / virtual / derived columns in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250389/computed-calculated-virtual-derived-columns-in-postgresql/8250729#8250729)

Related:

- [PostgreSQL: Which Datatype should be used for Currency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15726535/postgresql-which-datatype-should-be-used-for-currency/15729573)

Answer (score 1):

Most databases support generated columns.  If you really want a `salary` column in `voluntaryworker`, then you can use such a column:

```
create table voluntaryworker (
    pid integer references Person,
    salary generated always as (cast(null as float))
);
```

The exact syntax may vary, depending on the database.

Note that having a separate table seems utterly superfluous.  Why not just have a flag in the `worker` table.

Also, representing the salary as a `float` is quite troublesome.  In general, you really should never use floating point representations for monetary amounts.  `decimal`/`numeric` is much more appropriate for money.

Answer (score 0):

At least `insert into voluntaryworker (pid) values (1354);` leaves it NULL.