# Change "money" symbol on Beekeeper SQL

Tags: sql

I'm student of SQL using Beekeeper Studio/Postgres, and I need to create a column using money.
But when I do SELECT * FROM produto, shows me "R$", my local monetary symbol.
Can I change the R$ to ʛ not only in my Beekeeper, but to everyone?

```
CREATE TABLE produto(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  codigo_produto int NOT NULL,
  nome_produto VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  descricao_produto VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  estoque_produto int NOT NULL,
  fabricacao_produto date NOT NULL,
  valor_produto money NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO produto (codigo_produto, nome_produto, descricao_produto, estoque_produto, fabricacao_produto, valor_produto) values
(1, 'firebolt', 'vassoura randolph spudmore', 1, '1993-02-08', '2000'),
(2, 'cleansweep eleven', 'vassoura companhia de vassouras cleansweep', 15, '1995-08-01', '500');

SELECT * FROM produto
```

Comment: The currency symbol isn’t stored in your database. It’s added as a convenience by your GUI. It will always use your local system settings for currency formatting.

Comment: To complement previous comment, if you build an app you should define an environment to set user's currency format. You should also use the right datatype as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15726535/postgresql-which-datatype-should-be-used-for-currency