# Rails: Storing high currency values in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-6

I would like to store high value currency values into the DB.

I tried to use an `integer` field in my migration, however I get following error

```
PG::NumericValueOutOfRange: ERROR: numeric field overflow 
DETAIL: A field with precision 8, scale 2 must round to an absolute value less than 10^6.
```

So I then tried to use decimal with precision

```
t.decimal     :value, precision: 30, scale: 2
```

Once gain I am getting the same error when I enter

What I would like to know, is it possible, and how can I save a value like `1000000.0` into the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I tried to use an integer field in my migration, however I get following error
>
> ```
> PG::NumericValueOutOfRange: ERROR: numeric field overflow  
> DETAIL: A field with precision 8, scale 2 must round to an absolute value less than 10^6.
> ```

That's a misunderstanding. The error message is for data type `numeric` - `numeric(8,2)` to be precise - not `integer`.

#### Solution

Just use [**`numeric`** without precision and scale](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL). It stores decimal number (with any amount of fractional digits) exactly as given.

`decimal` is a synonym of `numeric` in Postgres.

If you don't have fractional digits, consider `integer` (max 2^31 - 1) or `bigint` (max 2^63 - 1).

Related:

- [PostgreSQL: Which Datatype should be used for Currency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15726535/postgresql-which-datatype-should-be-used-for-currency/15729573#15729573)